# iOS singleton shared instance and loading remote json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

This is my situation:

```
// data.m
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonData;

+ (Data *)sharedData
{
    static Data *sharedData;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        _sharedData = [[Data alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedData;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self clear];
        [self load]; // here i start loading my remote JSON data and fill self.jsonData
    }

    return self;
}
```

and I have

```
// main.m 
[Data sharedData].jsonData; // this return nil
```

the jsonData return nil , i think because the request to the server is not done yet..
How can I do for wait till the remote request is done?

Thanks.

EDIT:

here's my load method

```
[[ApiClient sharedClient] loadDataWithSuccess:^(NSMutableArray *data)
{     
    self.jsonData = data;
}
                                         fail:^(NSString *errorMessage)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
}];
```

`loadDataWithSuccess` returns void.

Comment: don't wait. use a delegate / block / notification and handle the callback instead.

Comment: Add observer to those that need to display the jsonData and post a notification once the jsonData is loaded? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Wain can u provide an simple example? many thx

Comment: The programming topic associated with @verbumdei comment above provides details. You need to configure an observer and post a notification (both using NSNotificationCenter). https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i

Comment: I have updated with my load method. Thanks

Comment: Maybe i can use my loadDataWithSuccess block better?

Comment: Yes you can. Post a notification using NSNotificationCenter inside the loadDataWithSuccess block. Try it first.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a singleton for this.  Very bad karma.

Comment: @verbumdei i have post into method [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeOtherEvent" object:nil]; but i need to return self only when receive notification! how can i do it?